# How to append arbitary list with {0} so that its length becomes a given integer k

Tags: list-manipulation

How to append arbitary list with `{0}` so that its length becomes a given integer `k`?

For example, when `k=3`, I need to make the list below:

```
{{8}, {7, 1}, {6, 2}, {6, 1, 1}, {5, 3}, {5, 2, 1}, {4, 4}, {4, 3, 1}, {4, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2}}
```

to

```
{{8, 0, 0}, {7, 1, 0}, {6, 2, 0}, {6, 1, 1}, {5, 3, 0}, {5, 2, 1}, {4, 4, 0}, {4, 3, 1}, {4, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2}}.
```

The point is to make the length of sublist equal to `k=3`.

Thanks very much!

Comment: `PadRight[#, k] & /@ list`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lst = {{8}, {7, 1}, {6, 2}, {6, 1, 1}, {5, 3}, {5, 2, 1}, {4, 4}, {4, 3, 1},
     {4, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2}};
```

[`PadRight`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight.html) does what you need automatically:

```
PadRight[lst]
```

> ```
> {{8, 0, 0}, {7, 1, 0}, {6, 2, 0}, {6, 1, 1}, {5, 3, 0}, {5, 2, 1}, {4, 4, 0}, 
>  {4, 3, 1}, {4, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2}}
> ```

If you need `k` columns, use `{Automatic, k}` as the second argument:

```
PadRight[lst, {Automatic, 5}]
```

> ```
> {{8, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {7, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {6, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {6, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
>  {5, 3, 0, 0, 0}, {5, 2, 1, 0, 0}, {4, 4, 0, 0, 0}, {4, 3, 1, 0, 0},
>  {4, 2, 2, 0, 0}, {3, 3, 2, 0, 0}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat long-winded and fussy version of @BobHanlon's comment:

```
padSubLists[ss_List, n_Integer] := Map[PadRight[#, n] &, ss]

padSubLists[{{8}, {7, 1}, {6, 2}, {6, 1, 1}, {5, 3}, 
{5, 2, 1}, {4, 4}, {4, 3, 1}, {4, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2}}, 3]
(* {{8, 0, 0}, {7, 1, 0}, {6, 2, 0}, {6, 1, 1},
   {5, 3, 0}, {5, 2, 1}, {4, 4, 0}, {4, 3, 1},
   {4, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2}} *)
```